# Do we need to treat uniqueness and existence separately for $r \in \{0,1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ such that $a \equiv r \, \mathrm{mod} \, n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then there is a unique integer $r \in \{0,1, \dotsc, n-1\}$ such that $a \equiv r \, \mathrm{mod} \, n$.

My question is with regards the unique existence of the nonnegative integer $r$. In the proof in the text, the author provided separate cases typically associated with unique existence proofs, showing uniqueness and existence separately.

My question is, since we can use the division algorithm upon dividing $a$ by $n$, we immediately obtain unique integers $q$ and $r \in \{0,1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ such that

$$a-r = nq$$

which implies that

$$a \equiv r \, \mathrm{mod} \, n$$

so I don't see how it is necessary to treat uniqueness and existence separately.

Comment: By using the division algorithm you obtain _a_ number $r$. You haven't shown that it is unique. There could be other $r$ that just doesn't get chosen by the division algorithm.

Comment: But doesn't the division algorithm provide the uniqueness of $r$? Or is that uniqueness lost somehow?

Comment: As I said, using a specific algorithm to divide $a$ by $n$ and procuring a remainder really only proves that some $r$ exists. It does not guarantee that every other algorithm (including guessing-until-you-find-one) finds the exact same one.

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong. How to prove that there is exactly one $x$ such that $x+3 = 5$? Saying $x=2$ is such that $x+3 = 5$ only shows that there is some $x$ such that $x+3 = 5$. To be more logically rigorous, one has to show also that $x$ cannot be other than $2$. :)

Comment: The statement is just a rewording of the Division Algortihm using modular language. Both are essentially equivalent (uniqueness of the quotient follows immediately). So if you haven't yet proven the Division Algorithm then it would be circular to invoke it.

Comment: @WalkingBlues Very good point!